# Using mxmlc to compile as files with more than one src paths

Tags: actionscript-3, mxmlc

I am using mxmlc.exe to compile my Flash project but I have two separated source files.

I noticed that I can specify more than one `-compiler.library-path` but it seems not OK to specify more than one `-compiler.source-path` parameters.

For some reasons I have to keep the src files in different folders. Is there any way I can still compile?

Thanks!

The desired command-line parameters:

```
mxmlc.exe src/Editor.as 
-output=Editor.swf 
-compiler.source-path=src1 -compiler.source-path=../src2
-compiler.library-path=libs -compiler.library-path=../libs
```

Answer (score 0):

The += operator will append the second path to compiler.library-path, whereas the = operator will replace the value with a new one.

try this instead:

```
mxmlc.exe src/Editor.as 
-output=Editor.swf 
-compiler.source-path=src1 -compiler.source-path=../src2
-compiler.library-path+=libs -compiler.library-path=../libs
```

You might have to play a bit with the spacing before and after the += to get it working exactly right.

Comment: thanks, actually the two `-compiler.library-path` parameters are both working fine. The issue is that the second `-compiler.source-path` is not working

Comment: did you try += on the second compiler.source-path param? this helped me out when i was having the same problem.